# angularJS: Loading image as ng-src appears in $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function in my controller that calls the Wikipedia API upon clicking an anchor on my page, which loads some data about an author. You can see an example of this data [here](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=eb1f9f27a05a3bb20955c39e71372c2c). If you look under Query > pages > id > thumbnail > original; you can see the url that I want assigned as ng-src upon calling this function.

So what happens is that my page loads, and the image is not showing (since it has no ng-src, I presume, but it's also not showing as broken - it's simply not there.

And when I call my function and update the object I want to call from the image still does not load.

Can somebody point out what I'm doing wrong?

my html:

```
<div class="authorInfoContainer" ng-show="author">
    <button ng-click="removeAuthor()">Close window</button>
    <img ng-src="{{page.thumbnail.original}}">
    <div class="container" ng-repeat="page in author.query.pages">
        {{ page.extract }}
    </div>
</div>
```

my controller (the relevant functions are getAuthorInfo and removeAtuhor - pasting the whole thing as I might have missed something):

```
'use strict';

angular.module('frontEndApp')
    .controller('WordsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        var url = 'http://localhost:3000/API/getWords';

        $scope.words = [];

        //custom order by function for the select drop-down
        $scope.orderByMe = function(x) {
            $scope.myOrderBy = x;
        };

        //function to get author info from wikipedia
        $scope.getAuthorInfo = function(author) {
            //remove whitespace from author
            author = author.replace(/\s/g, '+');
            //concat the get URL
            var url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&uselang=user&prop=extracts%7Cpageimages&titles=' +
                author + '&piprop=name%7Coriginal';
            //get author info from wikipedia    
            $http.get(url)
                .then(function successCallback(response) {
                    $scope.author = response.data;
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });
        };

        //function to clear author info
        $scope.removeAuthor = function() {
            $scope.author = null;
        };

        //function to get a random quote from the DB
        $scope.getRandomWord = function() {
            $http.get('http://localhost:3000/API/getRandomWord')
                .then(function successCallback(response) {
                    $scope.words = [];
                    $scope.words.push(response.data);
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });
        };

        //get all quotes from the DB on page load
        $http.get(url)
            .then(function successCallback(response) {
                $scope.words = response.data;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
    });
```

Comment: can you paste html that you can see in the browser?

Comment: The `<img>` tag should  be inside the `<div class="container">`, since you are referring to the `page` variable that loops the author pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template you're refering to a `page` variable on the scope that you never set. You set, however an `author`, which, as your `ng-repeat` points out, contains the pages. However, the `page` you access from outside the `ng-repeat` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing data in your example. What is `$scope.page` ? Since you are using `{{page.thumbnail.original}}`